# VSIX: How to require VS 2010 Service Pack 1

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I have a VSIX Visual Studio extension that will not function correctly if the user does not have Service Pack 1 installed in his/her Visual Studio.

Is there a way to prevent installing or give an error message when installing to VS2010 without SP1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to do this.
VSIX manifest schema [allows to specify supported version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393701%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but providing SP1 version there (10.0.40219.1) will stop vsix from working (it will give error during install).

Comment: I tried the same version number and got an error when installing, same as you. Disappointing!